# SQL Many to many to many

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue with a query I have to build. There are 3 tables,all many to many after one another.

```
Table Stores - id,store_name

Table Clients - id,store_id,client_name

Table Products - id,client_id,product_name
```

In a few words - One `Product` can be bought from many `Clients`. And one `Client` can be in many `Stores`.

The task is to get all `Stores` with the number of their `Clients` (a person is a client who bought at least one product. If that `client_id` does not bought at least 1 `Product` - he is not a real `Client`).

Comment: do a `left join` on all the tables with count(*)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT store_name, COUNT(store_name)
FROM Stores s
INNER JOIN Clients  c on (s.id = c.store_id )
INNER JOIN Products p on (c.id = p.client_id)
GROUP BY store_name
```

Answer (score 0):

get a count of clients and then do a `left join` among the tables like below

```
select s.store_name, 
t.client_count
from stores s left join
(
select c.store_id, count(p.id) as client_count
from Clients c left join products p
on c.id = p.client_id
group by p.client_id
) t on s.id = t.store_id
```